# How to find number of words in a phrase with spaces removed by checking v. dictionary

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a word, for example `"ilikesamsung"`, and a dictionary of words, for example:

```
{"i","like","the","king","sam","sung","samsung"}
```

I want to calculate number of spaces in this word, if we break it into the dictionary words. In the above example, the string is broken into `"i like samsung"`, and there are 2 spaces.

How can it be done?

**Elaboration:**

Problem has 2 parts-

1. Output Yes if this word can be broken.
2. Calculate number of spaces

**What I have tried:**

I have solved First part by Dynamic Programming.,

For the second part:

I have extended DP method to solve part2 . I took an array and I stored index at which word ends.  `arr[]={1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1}`

this gives answer 3.

I want answer 2, for this array should be `{1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}`.

Any advises?

Comment: You can use string matching algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) for this task:

```
f(0) = 0
f(i) = MIN { f(i-j) + (Dictionary.contais(s.substring(i-j,i)?1:INFINITY } for each j=1,...,i
```

The above finds the number of words in your string, so the final answer is `f(#characters)-1`

The idea is to do an "exhaustive search" - for a given new character - try to connect it to a word, and recursively invoke on what's left from the string.

This can be done pretty efficiently with DP techniques.